# Most common array elements

Tags: arrays, swift, nscountedset

I need to find the most common (modal) elements in an array.

The simplest way I could think of was to set variables for each unique element, and assign a count variable for each one, which increases every time it is recorded in a for loop which runs through the array.

Unfortunately the size of the array is unknown and will be very large, so this method is useless.

I have come across a similar question in Objective-C that uses an NSCountedSet method to rank the array elements. Unfortunately I am very new to programming, and could only translate the first line into Swift.

The suggested method is as follows:

```
    var yourArray: NSArray! // My swift translation

    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:yourArray];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];

    for (id obj in set) {
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[set countForObject:obj]]
            forKey:obj]; //key is date
    }

    NSLog(@"Dict : %@", dict);

    NSMutableArray *top3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];

    //which dict obj is = max
    if (dict.count>=3) {

        while (top3.count<3) {
            NSInteger max = [[[dict allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];

            for (id obj in set) {
                if (max == [dict[obj] integerValue]) {
                    NSLog(@"--> %@",obj);
                    [top3 addObject:obj];
                    [dict removeObjectForKey:obj];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"top 3 = %@", top3);
```

In my program I will need to find the top five place names in an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "top 5". Does your array contain equal elements multiple times? And you want to know those which are top most?

Comment: The array will contain a list of city names, where the user checked in. I need to sort through the elements in an array, to output the five places the user checked in, the most number of times. So yes there will be elements in the array repeated multiple times

Answer (score 15, accepted):

edit: now with Swift 2.0 below

Not the most efficient of solutions but a simple one:

```
let a = [1,1,2,3,1,7,4,6,7,2]

var frequency: [Int:Int] = [:]

for x in a {
    // set frequency to the current count of this element + 1
    frequency[x] = (frequency[x] ?? 0) + 1
}

let descending = sorted(frequency) { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

`descending` now consists of an array of pairs: the value and the frequency,
sorted most frequent first.  So the “top 5” would be the first 5 entries
(assuming there were 5 or more distinct values).  It shouldn't matter how big the source array is.

Here's a generic function version that would work on any sequence:

```
func frequencies
  <S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: Hashable>
  (source: S) -> [(S.Generator.Element,Int)] {

    var frequency: [S.Generator.Element:Int] = [:]

    for x in source {
        frequency[x] = (frequency[x] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    return sorted(frequency) { $0.1 > $1.1 }
}

frequencies(a)
```

---

For Swift 2.0, you can adapt the function to be a protocol extension:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element: Hashable {
    func frequencies() -> [(Generator.Element,Int)] {

        var frequency: [Generator.Element:Int] = [:]

        for x in self {
            frequency[x] = (frequency[x] ?? 0) + 1
        }

        return frequency.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    }
}

a.frequencies()
```

For Swift 3.0:

```
extension Sequence where Self.Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func frequencies() -> [(Self.Iterator.Element,Int)] {

        var frequency: [Self.Iterator.Element:Int] = [:]

        for x in self {
            frequency[x] = (frequency[x] ?? 0) + 1
        }

        return frequency.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your if-let-else can be simplified to `frequency[x] = 1 + (frequency[x] ?? 0)`

Comment: What is the Swift 3 syntax for this?

Answer (score 3):

For XCode 7.1 the solution is.

```
// Array of elements
let a = [7,3,2,1,4,6,8,9,5,3,0,7,2,7]

// Create a key for elements and their frequency
var times: [Int: Int] = [:]

// Iterate over the dictionary
for b in a {
    // Every time there is a repeat value add one to that key
    times[b] = (times[b] ?? 0) + 1
}

// This is for sorting the values
let descending = times.sort({$0.1 > $1.1})
// For sorting the keys the code would be 
// let descending = times.sort({$0.0 > $1.0})
// Do whatever you want with sorted array
print(descending)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as Airspeed Velocity, using a `reduce` instead of `for-in`:

```
extension Sequence where Self.Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func frequencies() -> [(Self.Iterator.Element, Int)] {
        return reduce([:]) {
            var frequencies = $0
            frequencies[$1] = (frequencies[$1] ?? 0) + 1
            return frequencies
        }.sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
    }
}
```

But please note that, here, [using `reduce` with a `struct` is not as efficient as a `for-in`](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/) because of the struct copy cost. So you will generally prefer the `for-in` way of doing it.

[edit: gosh, the article is by the same guy as the top answer!]