# How to find frequency of each element of Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Input : 1 3 4 2 3 1

Output:

Element 1 : Count 2

Element 3 : Count 2

Element 4 : Count 1

Element 2 : Count 1

```
var count:Int
let tempArray = [1, 1,1, 4 ,1]
var index  = 0
var fequency = [Int]()
for m in 0 ..< tempArray.count{
  fequency.append(-1)
}
print(fequency)
for i in 0 ..< tempArray.count{
  count = 1
  for j in i + 1  ..< tempArray.count{
    index = j
    if tempArray[i] == tempArray[j]{
      count = count + 1
   fequency [j] = 0
      print(fequency)
  }
    if fequency[i] != 0 {
        fequency[i] = count
     // print("frequency->",fequency)
    }

}
  print("\(tempArray[i]) occures at \(fequency[i]) times")
```

}

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27611871/6541007) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30545629/6541007)?

Comment: Thanks  OOPer but i was trying to solve without  inbuilt function  used in swift.

Comment: @akshay That post shows how to implement this yourself with a simple dictionary